# How to select using UNION all fields including NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use a query:

```
SELECT idFavourite AS entity, 'favourite' AS type 
FROM favourite 
WHERE idCar = 1 AND idUser = 1 
UNION
SELECT idLike AS entity, 'likes' AS type 
FROM `likes` 
WHERE idCar = 1 AND idUserLiked = 2
```

If second condition is not right, this query returns only one `type`. How I can get always two `type` of both queries?

**New query:**

```
SELECT likes.idLike AS likes, favourite.idFavourite AS fav FROM favourite

LEFT JOIN `likes` ON (likes.idCar = favourite.idCar) AND (likes.idUserLiked = favourite.idUser) AND
likes.idCar = 1 AND likes.idUserLiked = 2
```

Comment: please add desire output with column Name and there relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `union all` unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates (which is not possible in this case).  You can do:

```
SELECT idFavourite AS entity, 'favourite' AS type
FROM favourite 
WHERE idCar =1 AND idUser = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT idLike AS entity, 'likes' AS type
FROM `likes` 
WHERE idCar = 1 AND idUserLiked = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'likes'
FROM (SELECT 1 as x) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM likes WHERE idCar = 1 AND idUserLiked = 2);
```

Alternatively, if you only expect at most one row from the second subquery, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT idFavourite AS entity, 'favourite' AS type
FROM favourite 
WHERE idCar =1 AND idUser = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(idLike) AS entity, 'likes' AS type
FROM `likes` 
WHERE idCar = 1 AND idUserLiked = 2;
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns one row.  In this case, `entity` will be `NULL` if the `WHERE` clause filters out everything.

Comment: The last query returns me again only one row

Comment: @Gaga . . . The answer was directed toward the `likes` table, because your question suggests (to me) that was the problem.  However, the same ideas apply to the first subquery, so just use `max(idFavourite)` in the first subquery.

Comment: What do you think about my new query with JOIN?

Comment: @Gaga . . . That produces nothing similar to your original question.  It seems inappropriate in the sense that it invalidates the original question.